# Deploying a Java Web Service on a server

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have been asked to create a JAVAX-WS web service which basically performs some basic computation on the input to return the output. I also need to lookup some values from a database.
I am using this book :
**Java Web Services: Up and Running**
**What I've done so far** : 
1. Created the main java program containing the methods that perform the computations.
2. Used *wsgen* and *wsimport* to generate the various artifacts.
3. Used Endpoint to publish the service on localhost.
**What I need to do** : 
I need to get it running on something like a windows server for .NET services. So that it can serve multiple machines.
I know next to nothing about web services and servers, and have just gone through the first chapter of the aforementioned book so far.
From what all resources I've gone through I believe I could use GlassFish, but I don't know if it serves my purposes.
So if anyone could point to some helpful resources for the same, it would be extremely helpful.
**P.S** : I have no idea about looking up the required values from the database, so please point to some resource for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint can also serve requests concurrently, you can enable thread pooling by creating a ThreadPoolExecutor and registering it with the endpoint. See Endpoint.setExecutor(Executor executor)

If you want to deploy your Web Service on GlassFish you should change it into a WAR project, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html

Comment: And can you please clarify whether the glassfish serves the same purpose as windows server for the .net applications?

Comment: GlassFish is a reference implementation of Java EE Application Server. This is a Java application, you start it, you put your .war app in its deployment folder and GlassFish will start it. There are others servers like JBoss which do the same